# Ember call action in application route with return value

Tags: ember.js

In Ember you can call an action in your current context as you would a normal function, using `this.actions.actionName()`. This means the action can return a value.

In my login route, I am trying to call an action from the application route in this way. However `this.actions` only contains the actions in my login route.

**Login Route**

```js
actions: {
  test: function() {
    console.log(this.actions.sameRouteAction()); //5
    console.log(this.actions.applicationRouteAction()); // this.actions.applicationRouteAction() is not a function.
  },
  
  sameRouteAction: function() {
    return 5;
  }
}
```

**Application Route**

```js
actions: {
  applicationRouteAction: function() {
    return 7;
  }
}
```

What would `this.actions.applicationRouteAction()` have to become in order for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Ember 3.1.0, there isn't a way you can call the action directly on the parent route as a normal function like you can in the context of the current route/class. You can use the `send` function to send an action upward:

```
actions: {
  test: function() {
    this.send('applicationRouteAction');
  },
}
```

But you won't be able to get the return value of the `applicationRouteAction` function this way.

The two best options for communicating the result of the action from the parent route to the child route are:

1. Updating the model for the parent route via [transitionTo](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/Route/methods/transitionTo?anchor=transitionTo) or [refresh](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.1/classes/Route/methods/modelFor?anchor=refresh). This will update the route tree, and your child route can get the model of its parent via [modelFor](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.1/classes/Route/methods/modelFor?anchor=modelFor). Since you are using the Application route in your example, this seems like it's probably not the method you'll want to use.
2. Create or use an existing [Service](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.1.0/applications/services/) to communicate between the routes. You can inject the service in both locations, update its state from the Application route, and read its state from the child route.

If you can add more details about what you want the actions to do I can update this answer with more details about which pattern makes more sense and why!

Comment: Thank you. my main goal is to keep my code as DRY as possible, so in this case, I think moving the action from the application route into a mixin will do the trick.

Comment: If you’re going to go that route, I would recommend a utility function instead. Ember mixins are likely not going to stick around much longer, the framework is slowly shifting to use native classes instead of EmberObject and native classes do not have a concept of mixins yet. Definitely possible a native mixin solution will arise at some point, but utility functions are the safest bet.